# JetBrains Mono font settings

Tags: fonts

I have been trying to configure emacs to use [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) font, unfortunately i can hardly understand the way emacs handles font settings, there are way too many options and stuffs going on. So i got lost and here is my current font settings -

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "JetBrains Mono"
                    :height 110
                    :weight 'light)
(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil
                    :family "JetBrains Mono"
                    :height 1.0)
(set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil
                    :family "JetBrains Mono"
                    :height 1.0)
```

But this seems not as per recommended settings from the jetbrains's site -

```
Size: 13
Line spacing: 1.2
```

I don't know to relate `:height` with `Size: 13`, couldn't figure that out. I also failed to match the line spacing 1.2. If i use `(setq line-spacing 1.2)` emacs renders lines way too separated vertically.

I am using emacs 27.1 with harfbuzz.

So if anyone has been using this font with emacs, please share your configuration or point me to some place where i can get/understand how to configure and match the recommended settings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from my `custom.el`:

```
 '(default-frame-alist
    '((fullscreen . fullscreen)
      (font . "JetBrains Mono-13")
      (line-spacing . 0.2)))
```

The JetBrains website doesn't specify the unit for their recommendation of "13", but inspecting the CSS reveals that their examples have a CSS `font-size` of 13px.

Emacs documentation on fonts specifies that the sizes point sizes.<sup>[[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html#Fonts)]</sup>

Emacs on my macOS machine reports the value of `display-pixels-per-inch` as "72" whereas CSS specifies that a pixel is 1/96th of 1 inch.<sup>[[2](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#absolute-lengths)]</sup> Nevertheless, the value of 13 points in Emacs seems to be the same height in real display pixels as the 13 pixels on the JetBrains website in Chrome and Firefox and I can't understand why that would be.

The `line-spacing` property is set as a height spec and refers to the amount of space added below each line. Therefore, you only want the *extra* space more than a default, single line height. The value should be `0.2`.